# Pulumi: query pulumi stack value if not given

Tags: azure, pulumi

Here is my use case:

I have a blob resource that is created only if a file (artifcat from my CI server) is present on my build machine.

Now, I may have to run pulumi on my local machine where the file does not exist. But I don't want to delete the blob resource. The blob is still present on Azure.

```js
if (fs.existsSync(fullFileName)) {
    // On the build server, I update the blob with the new artifact
    const blob = new azure.storage.Blob("myblob-b", {
                    name: fileName,
                    source: fullFileName,
                    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
                    storageAccountName: storageAccount.name,
                    storageContainerName: zipDeployContainer.name,
                    type: "block"
                })
} else {
    // On my local machine, the artifact does not exists but I want to keep it
    const stackRef = new pulumi.StackReference(`${organization}/${projectName}/${stackName}`);
    const srblob = stackRef.getOutput("zipblob");
    // How do I tell pulumi keep the resource from the stack reference
}

export const zipblob = blob;
```

Comment: not sure where you want to retrieve the value from, pulumi config value or ???

Comment: Actually Pulumi detects if the value has changed if I don't set it which is fine. The current value is stored in the stack. Is the a way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm not smart enough for this, people on pulumi slack helped me out. Basically you can use [StackReference](https://pulumi.io/reference/pkg/nodejs/@pulumi/pulumi/#StackReference). Specifically the [getOutput](https://pulumi.io/reference/pkg/nodejs/@pulumi/pulumi/#StackReference-getOutput) method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost done, I'm missing the the last step after using getOuput. I exported the blob resource, and getOutput gives it back but I still can't tell Pulumi to not delete the resource.

Comment: i'm sure what you mean exactly, perhaps you should start a new question ;)